# IIS Multiple Websites access with name

Tags: iis, cgi

i have two django websites in CGI in my IIS WebServer that are binded with two different ports: 8080 and 8081, i need to access them with something like: myserver/app1 and myserver/app2.

How i can do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using this approach:

In Urls.py i've added a wrapper for all requests with these lines of code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?i)subDirectory/', include([ #Application Prefix in Webserver
    url(r'^(?i)$', app.views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^(?i)home', app.views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^(?i)contact', app.views.contact, name='contact'),]
```

Then modified the Static_Url property under settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/subDirectory/static/'
```

Then in IIS, under the main website i've added a new webapplication with the defaultAppPool and configured like indicated here (Omitting the point n°4): https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-python-django-web-app/

And added a virtual directory (under the application) in order to serve the statics (with caching rule fixed at 7 days) files with the following web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

With this approach, you'll be able to use a main site and place/serve multiple django applications without become crazy!

Enjoy!